# The highlight tag is not working when tried in mobile scripts

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

While performing mobile testing , The highlight tag is not working when tried in mobile scripts. The highlight is not working for validate tag too. Please confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Highlight tag or function is not there in Mobile testing. So we can't use Highlight tag in performing mobile Testing or mobile Automation.